# Javascript Array is Breaking my Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm having some difficulty with this two dimensional array that I've created.

I've declared it like so:

```
 var objects = new Array();
```

And then I run two loops, one inside the other, and in doing so, call values to the array, but it seems to break my entire loop (and thus the script) when it does run.

```
    for(var i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
        dirtRows++;
        document.getElementById("dirtTable").innerHTML+='<div class="dr" id="dirtRow-' + i + '"></div>';
        alert(i);
        for(var ii = 0; ii < 32; ii++) {
            dirtBlocks++;
            document.getElementById("dirtRow-" + i).innerHTML+='<div class="dirt" onclick="destroyIt(' + i + ',' + ii + ')" id="dirt-' + ii + '">' + ii + '</div>';
            objects[i][ii] = 1;
        }   
    }
```

What might I be doing wrong? It's definitely the Array that's breaking it.

Comment: `It's definitely the Array that's breaking it.` What array? `objects[i]` is `undefined` in your loop every time :). Did you try looking at your console/debugger what the issue could have been? Something similar to this: `Cannot set property '0' of undefined ` might have been displayed in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't created the inner arrays.

```
var objects = []; // Use an array literal, not new Array()
for (var i = 0; i <= 32; i++) {
    objects[i] = []; // Create sub-array
    dirtRows++;
    document.getElementById("dirtTable").innerHTML+='<div class="dr" id="dirtRow-' + i + '"></div>';
    alert(i);
    for(var ii = 0; ii < 32; ii++) {
        dirtBlocks++;
        document.getElementById("dirtRow-" + i).innerHTML+='<div class="dirt" onclick="destroyIt(' + i + ',' + ii + ')" id="dirt-' + ii + '">' + ii + '</div>';
        objects[i][ii] = 1;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great way of seeing it

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare objects[i] to be an array:

```
objects[i] = new Array();
objects[i][ii] = 1;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but I've declared the array already as stated in the post.

Comment: Yes, you have declared var objects to be an array. But you also have to declare that objects[i] is an array as well.

Comment: Arrays by definition are one-dimensional. To create two-dimensional arrays when programming, you have to create an array of arrays. You have already created the holder-array. You haven't created any of the inner arrays though that would give it the two-dimensionality that you seek.

Comment: Thank you @David That makes a lot more sense